# UI Automation retrieve incorrect children list of Windows 10 calculator application

Tags: c#, windows, .net-core, ui-automation

We would like to use UI Automation to automate windows 10 calculator.
We found out that **sometimes** we are not getting the correct number of children with findAll method.
We wrote small application that check every second the number of children and write it to the console:

```
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var condition = new AndCondition(
                            new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.ControlTypeProperty, ControlType.Window),
                            new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.NameProperty, "Calculator"));
            var calculatorAutomationElement = AutomationElement.RootElement.FindFirst(TreeScope.Children, condition);
            while (true)
            {
                var all = calculatorAutomationElement.FindAll(TreeScope.Children, Condition.TrueCondition);
                Console.WriteLine(all.Count);
                Thread.Sleep(1000);
            }
        }
```

The output of this application is 1 or 4 randomly.
Any suggestions?

Comment: The only time I have ever seen something like this was because there were so many events being raised in our WPF application that it was discarding the `OnCreateAutomationPeer()` events. Since this is the windows calculator you cant really change how it functions but I would try making sure the mouse is not on top of the window since this can cause animations like hovering over a button highlighting it which can raise events. Also I would look into reducing the window themes complexity like transparency on the title bar.

Comment: For our application the issue was that we had a ton of redundant events filling a combo box over and over so some times it would raise the `OnCreateAutomationPeer` event and some times it would have timed out already.

Comment: With UI Automation nothing is ever guaranteed as you're accessing a resource that's not yours. If you tweak slightly your program and remove the timeouts, you'll see the 1 and 4 much more often: https://pastebin.com/raw/Z0JbHswt they probably correspond to the UI that's being built/destroyed piece by piece and this is what UI Automation reports. You must always check for nulls when you search for items, insert timeouts if you don't find them (until you do), etc.